# Populate todays date as column name with values derived from existing column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a dynamic column in a table whose column name will be today's date and values will be populated based on a mathematical operation of an existing column. For example table, t1 has column a,b,c and I want to add a column called '04-26-2021' whose value will be a+b+c values. Does anyone know how we can implement it in Postgresql? Thanks

Comment: see if this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779734/dynamically-generate-columns-in-postgresql or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104508/postgres-dynamic-column-headers-from-another-table

Comment: You are looking for a "view", an object that looks like a table, but is a query with a name.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just call the column `today`?

Comment: @IanKenney Thanks for the suggestion. But I am not storing date values in any column. I want to generate dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

there are certain rules while naming a column in postgres, like you can't start the name with any digit, you have to use alphabets(lowercase) and only underscore is allowed in special characters. So, instead of '04-26-2021' you can try 'april_26_2023'.
here is simple way to do it using python and psycopg2.

```
import psycopg2
from datetime import datetime

# Setting the secret Key
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'any-secret-key-you-choose'

# Database Credentials
hostname = 'localhost'
username = 'your_username'
pwd = 'your_password'
port_id = 5432
database = "your_database_name"
cursor = None
conn = None


today = datetime.today()
d3 = today.strftime("%b_%d_%Y")

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host=hostname,
    dbname=database,
    user=username,
    password=pwd,
    port=port_id
)
    conn.autocommit = True
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f'''ALTER TABLE se_attendence_record ADD COLUMN {d3.lower()} 
    BOOLEAN''')

except Exception as error:
    print(error)
finally:
    if cursor is not None:
        # necessary to close the cursor.
        cursor.close()
    if conn is not None:
        # necessary to close the connection also.
        conn.close()
```